# Karamata's proof of Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem

Tags: real-analysis, generating-functions, tauberian-theorems

I understand Karamata's proof of the Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem as in http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/karamata.pdf, but what on earth is the motivation behind Lemma 4 - i.e, what would be the motivation to look at the space of all functions $g(x)$ for which $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} (1-x)\sum_{0 \leq i} a_i x^i g(x^i) = \int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx$ ?

Trying to prove the theorem by myself first then failing and seeing the proof, I find that to be coming out of nowhere and miraculously solving the problem.

Comment: I think the intuition is just that if only the characteristic function of [1/2, 1] (or whatever) were a polynomial, you’d be done. But, even though it’s not, you’re at least not dead because you can still get pretty close to it with polynomials. Then you just figure out if the polynomial approximations (in this case in L^1) you can produce are close enough, and they are. Writing that space down is just one way to formalize this. I dunno if this helps, probably not, but I figured I’d comment it just in case the idea (aka OK, replacing x with x^k tells me something, lin combos too) wasn’t clear.

Comment: @alpoge This is probably an extremely stupid question but (a) why I'm done if the characteristic function of [1/e, 1] is a polynomial (b) Why would you replace x with x^k (like why would you expect that would tell you something interesting) ?

Comment: To spell out alpoge's answer a bit: Suppose $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_i a_i x^i = S$. Then $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_i a_i x^{ki}=S$ for all $k \geq 1$ and, taking linear combinations, $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_i a_i p(x) = S p(1)$ for any polynomial $p(x)$ with $p(0)=0$. Now, let $q$ be the characteristic function of $[1/e,1]$. Then $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_i a_i q(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{i \leq \log x^{-1}} a_i = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^N a_i$. We want to show that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^N a_i = S$. If $q$ were a polynomial, then our first observation would finish the job.

Comment: Yep except everywhere there should be p(x^i) and q(x^i)!

Comment: Also @ChebotarevDensity in no sense is a question like that stupid, and also this is a really cool proof. Thanks for the interesting question! [For (b): well you have to try something, and replacing x by x^k is a natural thing to do... It’s hard to motivate certain things!]